# SoapUI. Build from source code fails with "unresolved dependencies"

Tags: java, maven, open-source, soapui

Did anybody ever successfully build SoapUI using sources from [this repo](https://github.com/SmartBear/soapui)?

I followed the steps according to the Readme, but it always fail with unresolved dependencies.

I thought that I can simply download sources, update maven indicies and build project. Or should I make any additional changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a first error because a dependency for "soapui" submodule is not found. It seems that SoapUI uses [install4j](https://www.ej-technologies.com/products/install4j/overview.html) but they have not installed it's jar in the [SoapUI maven repository](http://www.soapui.org/repository/maven2). I have searched for the jar on Internet and found a few available copies. One of them here:

```
http://corp.array.ca/nest-web/mavenrepo/com/install4j/i4jruntime/5.1.14/i4jruntime-5.1.14.jar .
```

Then I manually installed the jar:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=i4jruntime.5.1.14.jar -DgroupId=org.sonatype.install4j -Dartifact Id=i4jruntime -Dversion=5.1.14 -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=true -DcreateChecksum=true
```

A second error happens because SoapUI uses [animal sniffer check](http://mojo.codehaus.org/animal-sniffer/) to check that the project compiles for JDK 6.  When building with JDK 8 it fails. I have commented the execution of the plugin in the pom and the project builds fine. Just open the pom.xml file and delete the following lines:

```
 <executions>
      <execution>
          <id>animal-sniffer-check</id>
          <phase>process-classes</phase>
          <goals>
               <goal>check</goal>
          </goals>
     </execution>
 </executions>
```

Still these seem to be bugs of SoapUI and they should be reported.

Comment: I've re'cloned entire repository, but still i cannot build it. Now i'm getting error with install4j dependency.

Comment: What am i doing wrong? I have clean maven 3.0 installation and jdk7. Inaki, is there any opportunity to contact you outside stackoverflow? I cannot find any useful information about it :(

Comment: It is because that dependency is not available from the SoapUI maven repository. You need to manually install it. I'll provide detailed instructions when I'll be back at my desktop.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've imported that missing jar and tryied to rebuild. Now i'm getting this errors: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project soapui: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Roma/Downloads/soapui-next/soapui-next/soapui/src/main/java/com/eviware/soapui/autoupdate/Install4jSoapUIUpdateProvider.java:[14,32] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class ApplicationDisplayMode
[ERROR] location: package com.install4j.api.update

Comment: Seems like package com.install4j.api.update is missing. Inaki, it would be very, very cool and helpful if you could share you working project :|

Comment: I solved the issue. I found a working copy of 5.0.0 version in previous releases: https://github.com/SmartBear/soapui/releases/tag/5.0.0